# How to read the symbol © within a text

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I'm working on the copy for an album's liner notes, and text with the following structure is to appear:

> All songs © 2016 [publishing company X] and [publishing company Y], except tracks 3, 4, and 8 © 2016 [publishing company X].

My instinct is to put a period at the end of this phrase, as it *looks* and *reads* like a sentence even though it lacks a predicate. Is this because the © symbol stands for "are copyright" in this case? Is this a sentence?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to look to see if other liner notes use periods or not. It's just industry convention. I don't think any English grammar or style guides are going to have input here... But I might be wrong!

Comment: I always interpret it as meaning "copyrighted" (though while reading aloud I would simply say "copyright").

Comment: @HotLicks So it's more of an adjective with an implied predicate?

Comment: I think the bigger question is with regard to the year.  I can see syntactically replacing "copyrighted" with "written", but then there is an elided "in" that one must assume.

Comment: The use of this symbol no longer serves any purpose, because it is no longer necessary to indicate that something is copyrighted since the Bern convention: sadly, now every utterance is copyrighted by default. So you don't need any copyright notice at all: it serves no purpose.

Comment: The typographic designation for the symbol itself is a "copyright" sign.

Comment: @Cerberus Interesting. Should this say "published by" instead of ©?

Comment: @Cerberus Where do you get the idea that every utterance is copyrighted? Or that the notice serves no purpose?

Comment: @deadrat: When you post a Tweet, it is by the act of its creation automatically copyrighted: *Under the Berne Convention, copyrights for creative works do not have to be asserted or declared, as they are automatically in force at creation: an author need not "register" or "apply for" a copyright ... As soon as a work is "fixed", that is, written or recorded on some physical medium, its author is automatically entitled to all copyrights in the work, and to any derivative works unless and until the author explicitly disclaims them, or until the copyright expires.* en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright

Comment: The notice serves a purpose, since copyrights only apply for a limited period of time, and there is a difference in that limit depending on whether copyrighted by an individual or a corporation.  The notice explicitly sets the terms.

Comment: @Cerberus *When you post a Tweet, it is by the act of its creation automatically copyrighted* Maybe. The tweet must be "fixed" in a medium not considered transitory. This determination, like all copyright issues, is fact-based, i.e., tightly tied to each particular situation. In any case, I could tweet something in the public domain, something not copyrightable like a fact, or something copyrighted by another, and in those cases my tweet doesn't get "automatically" copyrighted. It's true that one may obtain copyright without a notice, but that's a far less sweeping claim than yours.

Comment: @Cerberus A copyright notice may not be necessary to retain copyright, but it's far from having no purpose.  It's presence defeats a defense of innocent infringement, and it's removal is evidence of intent to infringe.

Comment: **Yes, use a period just as you have written it.** It doesn't matter whether it is a "complete" sentence or not. The statement would look incomplete without the period. Don't overthink it. Just do it.

Comment: However the copyright right evolve, and will continue to, the question stays relevant: how to evaluate the symbol © as a syntactic element within an expression or a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

**It is a sentence (with some implied words), but the part of speech that the symbol is fulfilling in the sentence is open to the interpretation of the reader. It is most likely functioning as a verb or noun.**

The symbol represents the word "copyright," which can fulfill 3 different parts of speech:

> **copyright.**
>
> *[ˈkäpēˌrīt]*
>
> **As a NOUN:**
>
> 1. the exclusive legal right, given to an originator or an assignee to print, publish, perform, film, or record literary, artistic, or musical material, and to authorize others to do the same:
>
>    Example: "he issued a writ for breach of copyright" ·
>
>    Also: **a particular literary, artistic, or musical work that is covered by copyright.**
>
> **As an ADJECTIVE:**
>
> 1. protected by copyright:
>
>    Example: "permission to reproduce photographs and other copyright material"
>
> **As a VERB:**
>
> 1. secure copyright for (material).
>
> (Source: Oxford Dictionaries).

So we see that the symbol can fulfill multiple parts of speech in the sentence in question, with several possible readings of the sentence:

> 1. "All songs [*are*] **copyright**(s) [*of*]... [publishing company X] and [publishing company Y]" (adjective or noun).

Where "©" is a noun clarifying the songs as "musical work that is covered by copyright." It can also be read as an adjective stating that the songs have the quality of being protected by copyright.

> 2. "All songs [*are*] **copyright**(ed) [*by*]... [publishing company X] and [publishing company Y]" (verb).
>
> or
>
> 3. "All songs [*were*] **copyright**(ed) [*in*] 2016" (verb).

Where "©" is a verb describing the action taken by the publishing companies and/or in the year 2016 to protect the songs by copyright.

Finally, it's possible that the sentence might read (although the reader would have to read many more implied words into the sentence):

> 4. "All songs[*'*] **copyright**(s) [were acquired in] 2016 [by] [publishing company X] and [publishing company Y]" (noun).

Where "©" is a noun referring to the legal rights held on the songs by the publishing companies and acquired in the year 2016.